# Default mail program for using Mail merge

Tags: email, ms-office, macos

I am trying to finish the last step to mail merge on MS Word/MS Excel/MS Outlook on Mac.

The email option is not enabled and it says the default email program has to be set up to complete this step. I have tried changing the default email reader to MS Outlook which hasn't worked.

The MS office package is V.16.

How can I make the email option available?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367041/edit) your question to clarify a few points? When you say *"I have tried changing the default email reader to MS Outlook which hasn't worked"*, can you clarify *what* didn't work? Do you mean you tried to change the default mail reader and couldn't? Or, are you saying you successfully changed the default mail reader, but even so the email option is still greyed out? If you couldn't actually change the default mail reader, then please let us know *how* you tried to change it.